# Sync Azure Login in Blazor Server with Database

Tags: blazor, azure-web-app-service, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor Server-Side project with the default Azure/MS-Login Scheme. I have a Mysql database connected via Entity Framework where I store some external information about every user (f.ex. Roles, Orders etc.).

I want to automatically create a user in the database as soon as he is logging in. Now I found the following code for the `_Host.cshtml.cs`:

```
public async void Onget()
{   
    var identity = Request.HttpContext.User.Identity;
    string ObjectID = Request.HttpContext.User
                                         .FindFirst(u  => u.Type.Contains("objectidentifier"))?.Value;
    string Email = identity.Name;
    context.Users.Add(new User(ObjectID, Email));
}
```

This works fine, but I also thought of having the Rules from the database in the `AuthenticationStateProvider`, so I could use the `<Authenticated>` tag. How could I implement that? Should I use a second `AuthenticationStateProvider` (Microsoft Login automatically creates one).

Thanks

I tried creating a second `AuthenticationStateProvider`. But as soon as I wanted to update the credentials (UserSession) in the `AuthenticationStateProvider`, I got the following Error:

> JavaScript interop calls cannot be issued at this time. This is because the component is being statically rendered. When prerendering is enabled, JavaScript interop calls can only be performed during the OnAfterRenderAsync lifecycle method

This is, because I cannot access the local SessionStorage before the site is loading